# How to create multiple users in Django without letting them access each other's data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am not quite sure if the title I used for my question is the right one. And if this has previously been answered, someone should please point me to it as I have tried so much to find that out but its been futile.

I am currently working on a basic HR system which can be used by different companies. In a much clearer way, how can I create an online system whereby multiple companies can manage their employees online without having access to each other's data? And without even knowing that they use the same system? A perfect example of this kind of system is "Zoho People".

Comment: You can create 2 models. One for company and 2nd for employees connected with company model through ForiegnKey.

Comment: do you need the users to log in in your system too?

Comment: Yes @ThunderHorn, I need employees to log into the system too.

Comment: @phagyrhe then see my answer, you can give roles to the users so you know which one is HR, or Employee, and connect the both of them with a FK company, you have to extend the django user model and add the fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you should create your models something like that

if you want them both to log in in your system

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

ROLES =(
    ('hr', 'HR'),
    ('employee', 'Employee'),
    ('master', 'Master')
)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    [...] # your other fields    

class User(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLES, blank=False, null=False)
    [...] #your other fields
```

You can assign a role and company to each user.

Then to filter the queryset

```
User.objects.filter(company=request.user.company)
```

Another approach **if you want only to list/edit the employees of the company**, you can create an employee class **remove the role from user if you dont need it** and add company to the employee class

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    [...] #aditional fields
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. If I get this right, the first thing I will be required to do is to create a company account, two users account which are HR and employee and connect them to the company account using a foreign key, is this correct? If yes, will I do this for all the companies that decide to use the platform? Isn't there a way to automate this whereby upon creating a company account, an HR login details is automatically created. And then the person who holds these details can decide to create their employees with their login details.

Comment: @phagyrhe if you add a master role it will be possible. Well yeah when you register a company you will get a master account then you can register as many HR's and Employees as you wish

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I will keep this open for now so that I can work on the process you explained and then revert. If there is a need for me to ask any further questions, I'd do just that , otherwise, I will close it.

Answer (score 0):

A more organic way to achieve your goal is to use session and define a decorator for your views. For example I want to make sure that a user should not be able to access another user's data. So I defined a decorator that makes this check.

In my use case anonymous sessions are not allowed. To make sure user can access only their dashboard  I define a UserSession model and populate UserSession when user logs in.

I defined a decorator which checks if the session exists in Usersession. If it exists, a check is done to ensure user in UserSession and user in the request are same. If they match, the view is called. If not, an error response is sent. I am using JsonResponse. You can send appropriate response as per your use case.

For each view I use this decorator. Create as many decorator as per your use case and decorate your views with them.

1. For my use case I Defined a UserSession in models.py as follows:

   ```
    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    class UserSession(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   ```
2. I created a decorators.py in my app directory and defined is_user_logged_in method

   ```
    from functools import wraps
    from your_app.models import UserSession
    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
    from django.http import JsonResponse

    def is_user_logged_in(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            response_data={}
            try:
                userSession=UserSession.objects.get(
                    session__session_key=request.session.session_key
                )
            except UserSession.DoesNotExist:
                response_data['status'] = 'token_invalid'
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
            if userSession.user == request.user:
                return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                response_data['status'] = 'token_user_invalid'
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
        return wrapper
   ```
3. I decorated my views with is_user_logged_in decorator as follows:

   ```
    my_decorators = [is_user_logged_in, any_other_decorator]
    @method_decorator(my_decorators, name='dispatch')
    class ProfileView(View):
        def get(self, request):
            #Do your thing
        def post(self, request):
            #Do your thing
   ```

References:

[Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/)

[Decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/decorators/)

[Decorating Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)